# MySQL update takes huge time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have approx `230K` records in `MySQL` user table and i was updating `14K` user information via `php` with simple `foreach` from variable and using `update` query to update the column of `14K` user . It took `1 hour, 9 min approx` to run the query. First it took `13` min to update approx `1100 records` and than it took another `56` min to update the remaining records.

[image]

Is this usual or do i need to upgrade my system, where i am running. I have `8GB RAM, i5 processor 2nd gen` and using `ubuntu 14.04`.

If this is usual, what is the best way big companies handle such or bigger number of user records in fastest possible way in mysql ?

Just in case, if some one needs to know the exact code that ran.

```
foreach($_SESSION['tupple'] as $key => $value) {
    $commitUpdate = $mysqli->query("UPDATE user_table set col_name='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($value['col_name'])."' where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($value['id'])."'");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your 230K `UPDATE` queries in a *single* transaction?

Comment: @JohnCargo He said single transaction, not single query. Do you know what database transactions are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed things up using a prepared query, so it only has to parse the query once.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user_table SET col_name = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $col_name, $id);
foreach ($_SESSION['tupple'] as $value) {
    $col_name = $value['col_name'];
    $id = $value['id'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Also, if you're using InnoDB, start a transaction before the loop, and commit it at the end.

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
// above loop
$mysqli->commit();
```

It's also possible to update multiple rows in a single query:

```
UPDATE user_table
SET col_name = CASE id
    WHEN $id1 THEN '$name1'
    WHEN $id2 THEN '$name2'
    WHEN $id3 THEN '$name3'
    ...
END
WHERE id IN ($id1, $id2, $id3, ...)
```

You can use this type of syntax to group multiple entries in `$_SESSION['tupple']` into batches.

Comment: Ok! I didn't test the prepared query. I will test it with 1100 record , just to see, if it takes 9 min or arround or less ?

Comment: ok, and what would you suggest on better performance point of view. Single query or prepared query one ?

Comment: If you can do both, that would be best.

Comment: If you can only do one or the other, you'd have to benchmark it with your implementation to find out which is best, and how large the batches need to be.

Comment: Just last question sir, How would you tackle such situationt :- `mysql> alter table user_table change group_id group_id int after id;
Query OK, 232158 rows affected (36.13 sec)` is there any way arround other than updating or switching database ? `36` second is still high for one simple table change.

Comment: That simple table change has to rewrite every row in the table to move the column. There isn't really any way around it. Why do you care about the order of columns?

Comment: There was little change in column order in development environment and production environment. Migration was not done periodically.